# Trying to make "smart" crosshair in unity (using javascript)

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, unityscript, raycasting

This is my script:

```js
var ctexture : Texture2D;
function Update() {
var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Vector3(Screen.width/2,Screen.height/2,0));
var hit : RaycastHit;
if (Physics.Raycast (ray, hit, 100)) {
    var pointVec=Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(hit.point);
    GUI.Label(Rect(pointVec.x,pointVec.y,145,93),ctexture);
    Debug.DrawRay (ray.origin, ray.direction * 10, Color.yellow);
Debug.Log(hit.point);}}
```

I can see Debug.DrawRay ray and it's just how i wanted it to be. The problem is that i can't see result of GUI.Label. The ctexture is assigned and Debug.Log prints out correct info.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this in the OnGUI function? I believe that GUI calls will do nothing if they aren't in the right place. In any case I would advise that you use the new Unity UI system rather than the old and very limited legacy "GUI" system.

Answer (score 0):

Put the code in the OnGUI() function:

```
var ctexture : Texture2D;

function OnGUI() {
    var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Vector3(Screen.width/2,Screen.height/2,0));
    var hit : RaycastHit;
    if (Physics.Raycast (ray, hit, 100)) {
        var pointVec=Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(hit.point);
        GUI.Label(Rect(pointVec.x,pointVec.y,145,93),ctexture);
        Debug.DrawRay (ray.origin, ray.direction * 10, Color.yellow);
        Debug.Log(hit.point);
    }
}
```